# Cannot create a new React Native project

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg

I am trying to create new react native project, however I get this error:

> error An unexpected error occurred:
>   "/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v1/npm-@babel/helper-annotate-as-pure-7.0.0-beta.46-4cd76d5c93409ea01d31be66395a3b98a372792e/.yarn-metadata.json: Unexpected end of JSON input".

I used this command:

```
create-react-native-app myproject
```

Earlier I used the same code and create project suddenly it doesn't work

Note: My internet connection is good

Comment: Try `yarn cache clean`

Comment: @PritishVaidya thz its wrk fine now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the steps to follow:

- install the latest version of node.js
- npm install -g create-react-native-app
- create-react-native-app YOUR-APP-NAME
- cd YOUR-APP-NAME
- npm start

Assuming you are running from expo

*UPDATE*
create-react-native-app has been deprecated in favor of expo.

- npm install -g expo-cli
- download the expo client for ios or android
- expo init my-app-name
- cd my-app-name
- npm start

You can then open the expo app on your phone and if on ios make sure you are on the same wifi as your computer then you should see my-app-name in the expo app, open it and start live coding.

If using android you can scan a barcode i think.